# displaying two or more data series (some with empty values) in one chart

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, merge, mschart

I'm having a series with decimal values of energy consumption for every 15 minutes for one full year.This data is from the past. 
Now a prediction of the future energy consumption is made. However, here I only have values for every hour for a year.
I want to overlay these two series to see the difference. Because of the missing values in the second series, there is no consistent line. The line just breaks of.
Here is where I add the first series data.

```
dtlist.Add(new DataTable(tableIST));                            
dtlist[0].Columns.Add("Date");            
dtlist[0].Columns.Add("Volume1");
dtlist[0].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtlist[0].Columns[0] };
DataRow dr;
Series default2 = new Series("Default");

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString))
{                
    string query = "SELECT TIMESTAMP, LAST FROM " + tableIST;
    connection.Open();
    int i = 0;
    decimal sum = 0;
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {                            
                    dr = dtlist[0].NewRow();
                    dr["Date"] = reader.GetDateTime(0);
                    dr["Volume1"] = reader.GetDecimal(1).ToString().Replace(',', '.');                                
                    dtlist[0].Rows.Add(dr);
                    default2.Points.AddY(reader.GetDecimal(1).ToString().Replace(',', '.'));                                
                }                            
            }
        }
    }
    connection.Close();
}
chart1.DataSource = dttemp = dtlist[0];
```

Here is where I add the second series data and merge it.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    string query = "SELECT TIMESTAMP, LAST FROM " + tableName;                        
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                dr = dtlist[count].NewRow();
                dr["Date"] = reader.GetDateTime(0).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
                dr["Volume2"] = reader.GetDecimal(1).ToString().Replace(',', '.');
                dtlist[count].Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
    }
    connection.Close();
}

//merge data in one datatable for displaying

dttemp.Merge(dtlist[1]);
```

Here is a picture how my chart looks now. 
 The blue line is the first data series and the yellow line is the second. 
[image: chart1]

It should look something like this. 
[image: chart2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first series for every 4 values (4, 15min values) make the average (that will give you the average hour value) and now you can draw the chart

Comment: This is a good solution. However, I'm curious if there is also a solution without taking the average of the 4 values and interpolate the missing values from the second series.

Comment: yes, you can multiply every value from the 2nd series 4 times (just copy it) and then you will have the same number. but i recommand the first one

Comment: I decided to go for the second approach but I didn't just copy the values. Instead I calculated the difference between two values and divided it by four. Then I add it four times to the first value with the corresponding time. Now it works fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem .. Any time

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I acually use.

```
                DateTime helpDate;
                Decimal helpNumber = 0, helpNumber2, difference;
                DataTable dthelp = new DataTable();
                dthelp.Columns.Add("Date");
                dthelp.Columns.Add("Volume" + CountPlusOne);
                dthelp.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dthelp.Columns[0] };
                int i = 0;
                foreach (DataRow row in dtlist[count].Rows)
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        helpNumber2 = Decimal.Parse(row["Volume" + CountPlusOne].ToString().Replace('.', ','));
                        difference = (helpNumber - helpNumber2) / 4;
                        helpDate = DateTime.Parse(row["Date"].ToString());

                        dr = dthelp.NewRow();
                        dr["Date"] = helpDate.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(45));
                        dr["Volume" + CountPlusOne] = (helpNumber - difference).ToString().Replace(',', '.');                            
                        dthelp.Rows.Add(dr);

                        dr = dthelp.NewRow();
                        dr["Date"] = helpDate.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
                        dr["Volume" + CountPlusOne] = (helpNumber - difference * 2).ToString().Replace(',', '.');                            
                        dthelp.Rows.Add(dr);

                        dr = dthelp.NewRow();
                        dr["Date"] = helpDate.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
                        dr["Volume" + CountPlusOne] = (helpNumber - difference * 3).ToString().Replace(',', '.');
                        dthelp.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                    i++;
                    helpNumber = Decimal.Parse(row["Volume" + CountPlusOne].ToString().Replace('.', ','));
                }
```